# JS querySelector not working even the code is very simple

Tags: javascript, html

please help me as i am learning JS now and for some reasons querySelector not working 
the website:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dicee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../testimgs/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>the test new </h1>
  </body>

  <footer>
    www  App Brewery  com
  </footer>
</html>
```

and i open google chrome console and use this small script and not working :

```
var h1 =document.querySelector("h1");
```

the problem is that  variable h1 get nothing and is empty and is null

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to add your JavaScript code as well.

Comment: What is not working with that code? For me the variable `h1` has the selected DOM element.

Comment: that is the problem the variable h1 get nothing and is empty and is null

Comment: @WaleedAhmed [I'm unable to reproduce that](https://jsfiddle.net/2obyhf7z/) with your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @WaleedAhmed The code you show works fine as shown in the link in my previous comment. If we can't reproduce the error, we wont be able to help you.

Comment: @Ivar i got you now but that is the problem as everything should go smooth also i will provide you with an image from the error and thanks for your help

Comment: @WaleedAhmed Using the code you provided, [it works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnZ3w.png). Is your site in a frame/iframe or something? Try to click [the little iframe button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3D4T.png) on the top right of your developer tools and see if you are able to select another frame. Then try your code again.

Comment: i tried it again and yes i can choose any frame but still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look below. The console log shows it is selecting your `<h1>`, the code should select your h1 so long as that is what you're trying to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dicee</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../testimgs/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>the test new </h1>
  <footer>
   www  App Brewery  com
  </footer>
  <script>var h1 =document.querySelector("h1"); console.log(h1);</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Just remove `console.log(h1);` if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks but didn't work :/ and when i am using the console in any browser not working :/

Comment: You're typing it directly in the console? You can remove the `<script></script>` tags on the code in the snippet and add it along with the console log, it should pop out `h1`. But you can keep it where it is, just below the footer in your html file.

Comment: In any event, the snippet above selected your `<h1>` element. It is working. You can type `var h1 = document.querySelector("h1"); console.log(h1);` directly into the console, and it will display 'h1`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys , the point that you all are correct , it worked finally.The problem just happens if i run the website directly from dream waver and trying to use the console to effect it.When i open the website directly from the wamp server Dir. folder it worked smoothly . Thank you all